# Can we get tab focus on ngdialog close (*) icon?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, ng-dialog

Code follows

```
dialog = ngDialog.openConfirm({
    scope: scope,
    template: 'Templates\\Directives\\errorModal.html',
    classname: 'ngdialog-theme-default custom-width',
    appendClassName: 'ngdialog-custom-screen-error',
    showClose: true,
    controller: 'control',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    preCloseCallback:function() {
        $rootScope.globalError = false;
    }
});
```

Here, errorModal.html content displaying.